# Symmetric Operators in Lang’s Linear Algebra p.219

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

I’m having trouble understanding how Lang in his third edition of *Linear Algebra* “reformulated” theorem 3.1 into 4.1.

This is theorem 3.1, which I totally understand:

> Let $A$ be a symmetric $n$ by $n$ real matrix. Then there exists a nonzero real eigenvector for $A$.

This is theorem 4.1, which was said to have been reformulated from the above:

> Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space with a positive definite symmetric bilinear form. Let $A:V\to V$ be a symmetric linear map. Then $A$ has a nonzero eigenvector.

I don’t know how 4.1 is related to 3.1 and I’ve been trying to figure this out for some time. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain how "real" is translated into the theorem 4.1 situation?  There's only one ingredient in the 4.1 theorem that it can be...

Comment: That’s all the book says. I’m not quite sure I know what you mean by explaining that.

Comment: $n$ by $n$ matrix is a special case of Theorem 4.1 by taking $V=\mathbb{C}^n$.

Comment: Find an orthonormal basis for $V$, and consider the matrix represntation of $A$ relative to that basis.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, since the orthonormal basis makes $A$ symmetric - thus there exists a nonzero eigenvector by 3.1, right?

Comment: The matrix of $A$ relative to the orthonormal basis*

Comment: My guess for the answer to Eric's question is that if you look at the context of theorem 4.1 in the book, you will find that Lang is talking about real vector spaces at that point, not complex ones. And yes, if you have an orthonormal basis for $V$, that produces an isomorphism between $V$ and $\Bbb R^n$ for some $n$. That isomorphism converts $A$ into a real symmetric matrix.